# How to show CircularProgressIndicator before Flutter App Start?

Tags: json, async-await, flutter, future, progress-indicator

In my demo app I need to load a 2 JSON file from server. Both JSON has large data in it. I my Flutter app I call the json using Future + async + await than I call to create a widget with runApp. In the body I try to activate a CircularProgressIndicator. It shows appBar and its content as well as empty white page body and 4 or 5 seconds later loads the data in actual body.

My question is I need to show the CircularProgressIndicator first and once the data load I will call runApp(). How do I do that?

```
// MAIN
void main() async {
    _isLoading = true;

  // Get Currency Json
  currencyData = await getCurrencyData();

  // Get Weather Json
  weatherData = await getWeatherData();

   runApp(new MyApp());
}



// Body
body: _isLoading ? 
new Center(child: 
    new CircularProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent.shade700,
    )
) :
new Container(
    //… actual UI
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the data/or loading indicator inside a scaffold, show the scaffold everytime whether you have data or not, the content inside you can then do what you want to do.`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Hello Rectangle',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello Rectangle'),
        ),
        body: HelloRectangle(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class HelloRectangle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        height: 400.0,
        width: 300.0,
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: buildText(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
               return CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.blue);
              } else {
               return Text(
                  'Hello!',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future buildText() {
    return new Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 5), () => print('waiting'));
  }
}
```

`

Comment: @ThaSalani the body: is inside the scafold. I dont get it. Can you provide a deme code please

Comment: Everything you show is in 'runApp' as that runs the app. You should do 'runApp' directly. In 'MyApp' do the data loading, show the progress indicator and show the data when it is finished. Currently you are awaiting the data to start the app, that is the white screen you see.

Comment: @Rene, I need to load 4 or 5 json. do you have any working examples?

Comment: @TheSaleni I did. I m trying. Thanks

Comment: @TheSaleni thanks. Modifying my project it is working now.